# Jquery select the right tab on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tabs

I try to use this on my web app http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/09/02/tab-styles-inspiration/comment-page-1/#comments it works fine, but now what I need is to load a new page and select the fine tab.
So instead of this dynamic stuff:

```
            <section>
            <div class="tabs tabs-style-topline">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#section-topline-1" class="icon icon-home"><span>Home</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-topline-2" class="icon icon-gift"><span>Deals</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-topline-3" class="icon icon-upload"><span>Upload</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-topline-4" class="icon icon-coffee"><span>Work</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-topline-5" class="icon icon-config"><span>Settings</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <div class="content-wrap">
                    <section id="section-topline-1"><p>1</p></section>
                    <section id="section-topline-2"><p>2</p></section>
                    <section id="section-topline-3"><p>3</p></section>
                    <section id="section-topline-4"><p>4</p></section>
                    <section id="section-topline-5"><p>5</p></section>
                </div><!-- /content -->
            </div><!-- /tabs -->
        </section>
```

I'd like to have

```
<section>
    <div class="tabs tabs-style-topline">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/route1" class="icon icon-home"><span>Home</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="/route2" class="icon icon-gift"><span>Deals</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="/route3" class="icon icon-upload"><span>Upload</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="/route4" class="icon icon-coffee"><span>Work</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="/route5" class="icon icon-config"><span>Settings</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="content-wrap">
            <div layout:fragment="content">

            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /tabs -->
</section>
```

I want this to reload my page and select the tab I clicked. I think it's not a big deal to do but I'm not verry powerful in web stuff.

Thank's

Comment: You'll have to edit the library to save the selected tab to a cookie, and on reload read the cookie and select the correct tab again...